# how to do a web service login with iOS

Tags: php, mysql, ios, session, cookies

I have created a database in mysql and multiple different php scripts to manipulate and add data to the database, and I am comfortable communicating between them using the iOS interface.

What I am interested in learning is the best way to handle a username and password login for my app. Once I have created a username and password or validated that a username and password combination is correct, what do I do?

Currently I have myself passing a user id number to the phone on login and to the server for every database transaction, but this feels like the wrong way to go about this.

Can someone explain the standard way to go about this? I have been researching cookies, which I understand to be holding something 'like' a user id number which is stored on the phone, and other information. I don't entirely understand how this is meant to work, however, and I want my service to be somewhat secure (so logging in actually means something).

Currently the user id number is always the same (id in database) so I assume that is not very secure.

Comment: Look into auth tokens. A lot of services use this now after the login/initial handshake.

Comment: I don't need something that secure, I just want to know what the server should pass down on a successful login, what the client passes up on http requests to show it is who they claim to be, and what is stored on both ends to make sure this all goes smoothly

Comment: If you don't want something super secure then you don't have to implement something like devise. But transmitting an auth token is much better than sending user ID up/down. It's easy to implement, makes your service more secure, and makes logging in mean something. All the server does on a successful login is generate a hash string that is saved for that user, then passed it down to the app. The app will transmit that hash up to the server on each request to verify the user.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help! To implement this do I need a third party software or can I do it from directly in my database? Is this hash string random? Could you refer me to a tutorial?

Comment: You can use things like Custom-PHP-Devise (https://github.com/lavanya-nyros/Custom-PHP-Devise) or OAuth to do it for you. If you're generating it on your own, then you need to implement some randomness to your hash string, otherwise it's the same as just using user-id as the authentication in your requests. At the very least, people say to do timestamp of the request + take parts of the request body/header + some of the user info to create the hash. The main thing though is that you generate a hash on user login then use that to authenticate the user, no matter how you create the hash.

Comment: And for reference, when is that auth token valid and when and how does it expire? I assume on logout I delete it or set it null. Then on all requests from the user I send up the token and check that it is valid for that username?

Comment: That depends on your implementation. I've seen it be device specific so if you log in from the computer, you'll log your user out from his phone (or if logging in from iPad, will log out of iPhone). Generally on log in you generate a new hash, log out or logging in on a different machine you delete it. Some implementations have a hash expire yearly, while others never expire. Really depends on your needs. I would just go with a framework on PHP that does it for you honestly and just hook into it